# collapsing a telescope image cone into an optical fiber

Tags: optics, lasers, fiber-optics

I have an application where a telescope will be receiving light from a laser source, and I need to couple the output, which is the image cone, into an optical fiber. Does anyone have any suggestions as to the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: is the image cone necessary when incoming photons travel in parallel paths and can exit parallel?

Comment: Welcome Anthony to Engineering and Physics Stack Exchanges.  I notice this question is [cross-posted on physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/778009/145491). This is [discouraged but not forbidden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/356966), but when a question is cross-posted it is polite to provide a link on each question to the other so people know and don't duplicate effort. See [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/646821/145491) and [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/18054/26438) for an example of how this is done.